# Css scale make some fonts resize strangely with missing parts of glyhs/characters

Tags: css, fonts, scale, css-transforms, text-rendering

I'm doing a webapp for an epub viewer. In that viewer, one of the feature is to zoom the page so the reader can read the text better.

What I'm doing now is create a scaleContainer div (or just the body) and place all of the epub contents in there while respecting the original css styling that the epub has. Then I use a css transform origin at top left of 0,0 and scale at zoom factor.

For a small selection of fonts, the fonts are rendered with missing parts of a character.

Here's a scaling at 1.9 which looks normal
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Hsv.png

Here's a scaling at 2.0, which looks really messed up
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOYfK.png

If you look at characters 'd' and 's' and 'g' at the image for scale 2.0, some parts of the fonts are missing.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Thanks.

**EDIT**

For most simplest form of what I'm trying to do that can reproduce this behavior:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Test page</title>

  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Akzigbql";
      src: url(fonts/Akzigbql.ttf);
    }

    p.copyright {
      font-size: 0.8em;
      line-height: 1.3em;
      text-align: center;
      text-indent: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      font-family: "Akzigbql";
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="scaleContainer">
    <p class="copyright">a division of Holtzbrinck Publishing Holdings Limited Partnership</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    let scaleFactor = 2
    let scaleContainer = document.querySelector('#scaleContainer')
    scaleContainer.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
    scaleContainer.style.transform = `scale(${scaleFactor})`;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**FONTS**

I'm not sure if its legal to post the fonts...but I'll remove it if there's an issue:
https://mega.nz/folder/YHJ0mZ7T#e3SBf8VQwlzCr22UrymlJA

Comment: Can you add your code? It would be helpful see what is going on.

Comment: I added the only the necessary code that does the same logic for my webapp. To reproduce this, you'll need to download the fonts. I'm not sure if this is legal to share the fonts but I'll take it down if it's necessary.